# Android SurfaceTexture.detachFromGLContext Error during detachFromGLContext

Tags: android, opengl-es, textureview

I'm trying to use TextureView on videos and it is crashing a lot on when trying to SurfaceTexture.detachFromGLContext.

I haven't found anything on Google, does anyone have a clue of what it could be?

Thanks

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error during detachFromGLContext (see logcat for details)
       at android.graphics.SurfaceTexture.detachFromGLContext(SurfaceTexture.java:195)
       at android.view.TextureView.destroySurface(TextureView.java:243)
       at android.view.TextureView.destroyHardwareResources(TextureView.java:355)
       at android.view.HardwareRenderer$Gl20Renderer.destroyResources(HardwareRenderer.java:2311)
       at android.view.HardwareRenderer$Gl20Renderer.destroyResources(HardwareRenderer.java:2318)
       at android.view.HardwareRenderer$Gl20Renderer.destroyResources(HardwareRenderer.java:2318)
       at android.view.HardwareRenderer$Gl20Renderer.destroyResources(HardwareRenderer.java:2318)
       at android.view.HardwareRenderer$Gl20Renderer.destroyResources(HardwareRenderer.java:2318)
       at android.view.HardwareRenderer$Gl20Renderer.destroyResources(HardwareRenderer.java:2318)
       at android.view.HardwareRenderer$Gl20Renderer.destroyResources(HardwareRenderer.java:2318)
       at android.view.HardwareRenderer$Gl20Renderer.destroyResources(HardwareRenderer.java:2318)
       at android.view.HardwareRenderer$Gl20Renderer.destroyResources(HardwareRenderer.java:2318)
       at android.view.HardwareRenderer$Gl20Renderer.access$800(HardwareRenderer.java:1895)
       at android.view.HardwareRenderer$Gl20Renderer$2.run(HardwareRenderer.java:2303)
       at android.view.HardwareRenderer$Gl20Renderer.safelyRun(HardwareRenderer.java:2254)
       at android.view.HardwareRenderer$Gl20Renderer.destroyHardwareResources(HardwareRenderer.java:2297)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.destroyHardwareResources(ViewRootImpl.java:853)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1534)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6585)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: The exception says `see logcat for details`, indicating that there are messages in logcat above or below the exception.  You should locate those messages and include them in your question.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this locally, it's only happening in production.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you must call this method `detachFromGLContext()` from GLThread.The method `queueEvent()` in **GLSurfaceView** can do this job.

```
 /**
 * Queue a runnable to be run on the GL rendering thread. This can be used
 * to communicate with the Renderer on the rendering thread.
 * Must not be called before a renderer has been set.
 * @param r the runnable to be run on the GL rendering thread.
 */
public void queueEvent(Runnable r) {
    mGLThread.queueEvent(r);
}
```

Comment: The issue is seen with TextureView not SurfaceView or GLSurfaceView. Though this answer has some value regarding call needing to be done on GL thread. The thing is that Android is making the call to detachFromGLContext so its hard to tell if its on the correct thread.